# MySQL connector NET 6.7.9 - Fix for "common" problems with WinRT assembly

Tags: c#, ssl, mysql-connector, windows-1252

I was working on Windows Universal App in which I'm using MySQL connector NET 6.7.9 to communicate with database. The WinRT assembly caused me a lot of pain. 
A to right now those were major problem:

1. How to fix SSL exception while opening connection?
2. How to fix windows-1252 encoding not supported exception while opening connection?

Those are all problems I had so far, if I find something new I'll update this post.

Comment: I commend your willingness to want to try and share your solution, but you must remember that this is a *Question* and *Answer* site. You should rephrase your post into a single question, and answer it below.

Comment: Ok, I am on it.

Answer (score 0):

1. SSL exception

While connecting connector throws exception where SSL connection is not supported:

Fix - add SSL Mode=None; to connection string:

```
public static void AssignConnection()
{
    string MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;" +
    "DATABASE=test;" +
    "UID=root;" +
    "PASSWORD=;" +
    "SSL Mode=None;"

    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
    connection.Open();
}
```

2. windows-1252 encoding not supported exception

If you "fixed" problem 1 you probably encountered windows-1252 encoding exception.

Fix - add charset=utf8 to connection string:

```
public static void AssignConnection()
{
    string MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;" +
    "DATABASE=test;" +
    "UID=root;" +
    "PASSWORD=;" +
    "SSL Mode=None;" +
    "charset=utf8";

    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
    connection.Open();
}
```

Comment: Hello, You must not put space between SSL and mode. it must be "SslMode=None"